# Taking ownership of a 64 GB USB flash drive

Tags: windows-7, usb, permissions, usb-flash-drive, ownership

Whenever I try to take ownership of my Kingston DTSE9G2 64 GB USB 3.0 flash drive the Windows Security / Explorer windows gets stuck on "Changing ownership of:" which never recovers, even if attempting to cancel the process. The only way to get the window to close is by manually disconnecting the USB which then corrupts the USB and requires reformatting.

This issue is consistent across 3 different PCs running Windows 7 64-bit with Service Pack 1 (2 on a domain, 1 off a domain) regardless of USB connection version (2 and 3), USB driver versions, local user profile, and rebuilding the partitions from scratch and reformatting as NTFS many times.

Given this, I concluded that the hardware may be faulty so I submitted a Return Merchandise Authorization and had it replaced but the issue remains.

Interestingly, the same issue occurs with a Corsair FLASH VOYAGER SLIDER 64GB USB 3.0 but not on 2 different PCs running Windows 8.1 64-bit Pro.

Is this a bug with Windows 7?

Here is the main screen I get stuck on:
[image]

Here is the entire process that goes around in one big loop:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Just a note: NTFS is a poor choice for a flash drive, exFAT is better. (Unless you want to use it on XP or Linux without additional drivers.)

Comment: @gronostaj: I'd say NTFS is a reasonably good choice for people who have lost several flashdrives worth of data to unreliable FAT data structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following elevated commands successfully granted ownership of the 64 GB USB flash drives to my logged on user:

1. `takeown /F driveLetter: /R /D Y`
2. `icacls driveLetter: /setowner domainOrHostname\username /T /C`

Command #2, icacls, is much faster but consistently reports the following, for some reason:

> Successfully processed x files; Failed processing x files

Maybe those failures (only 1 or 2) are what was tripping up Explorer?